# Jquery find behavior in firefox 3.5.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have the following piece of HTML code on my page:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="test" value="">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="ffb-input watermark">
      <div class="ffb">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In JavaScript I get the `<tr>` element using jquery and trying to search for input like this:

```
tr.find('div input:hidden')
```

but nothing is returned. When I'm using find like this:

```
tr.find('div input[type=hidden]')
```

Everything is working fine. What is the reason for such behavor?
I observe this only in FireFox 3.5.9, not in 3.6.3, Jquery 1.4.2

Comment: What does `alert(tr.find('div input[type=hidden]').width());` and `alert(tr.find('div input[type=hidden]').height());` give you in FF 3.5.9?

Comment: Yes, you're right, FF 3.5.9 gives value of 162 for width, whereas FF 3.6.3 gives zero.

Answer (score 0):

The `type` attribute does not seem to be taken into account for the `:hidden` selector. As noted in the comments, it *should* be, so you might want to [file a bug](http://dev.jquery.com/).

This seems to be the [code](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L219) for `:hidden`:

```
if ( jQuery.expr && jQuery.expr.filters ) {
    jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function( elem ) {
        var width = elem.offsetWidth, height = elem.offsetHeight,
            skip = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "tr";

        return width === 0 && height === 0 && !skip ?
            true :
            width > 0 && height > 0 && !skip ?
                false :
                jQuery.curCSS(elem, "display") === "none";
    };

    jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
        return !jQuery.expr.filters.hidden( elem );
    };
}
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong, but you can try to debug this code and submit a patch, perhaps ..

Comment: Actually, it *does* match `input type="hidden"` - http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector

Comment: @dragoon - Sorry, didn't notice that detail. You might want to file a bug.